# Is it possible to read android tag via RFID-RC522

Tags: python

So, I googled for two days and didn't get correct answer.
Is it possible to read NDEF data from Android phone via RFID-RC522?

I've tried to use couple of libs to solve this issue.
Also I've tried to write tag by phone and read it via RFID-RC522.

I get auth error each time I use phone or tag written by phone.

Comment: I've read in the past that PN532 *should* work - but it's been years since I looked into it

Comment: which phone app are you using for writing the tag? .... what do you mean by `didn't get correct answer`?